# OLS of statsmodels does not work with inversely proportional data?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to perform a Ordinary Least Squares Regression with some inversely proportional data, but seems like the fitting result is wrong?

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.arange(100, 0, -1)
x = np.arange(0, 100)

result = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(20, 4), sharey=True)
ax.plot(x, result.fittedvalues, 'r-')
ax.plot(x, y, 'x')

fig.show()
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding a constant as the [documentation suggests](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html), so it's trying to fit the whole thing as `y = m x`.  You wind up with an `m` which is roughly 0.5 because it's doing the best it can, given that you have to be 0 at 0, etc.

The following code (note the change in import as well)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.arange(100, 0, -1)
x = np.arange(0, 100)
x = sm.add_constant(x)

result = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 8), sharey=True)
ax.plot(x[:,1], result.fittedvalues, 'r-')
ax.plot(x[:,1], y, 'x')

plt.savefig("out.png")
```

produces

[image: plot showing the match]

with coefficients of `[ 100.   -1.]`.