# (Python) MVHR Covariance and OLS Beta difference

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I calculated the minimum variance hedge ratio (MVHR) of two securities' returns by:
1. Calculating the optimal h* = Cov(S,F) / Var(F) using samples
2. Running an OLS regression and obtain the beta value

Both values differ slightly, for example I got h* = 0.9547 and beta = 0.9537. But they are supposed to be the same. Why is that so?

Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

var = np.var(secRets, ddof = 1)
cov_denom = len(secRets) - 1
for i in range (0, len(secRets)): 
   cov_num += (indexRets[i] - indexAvg) * (secRets[i] - secAvg)
cov = cov_num / cov_denom
h = cov / var

ols_res = sm.OLS(indexRets, secRets).fit()
beta = ols_res.params[0]

print h, beta
```

indexRets and secRets are lists of daily returns of the index and the security (futures), respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also a case of missing constant in OLS regression. The covariance and variance calculation subtracts the mean which is the same in the linear regression as including a constant. statsmodels doesn't include a constant by default unless you use the formulas.

For more details and an example see for example [OLS of statsmodels does not work with inversely proportional data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723339/ols-of-statsmodels-does-not-work-with-inversely-proportional-data)

Also, you can replace the python loop to calculate the covariance by a call to `numpy.cov`.