# How stats model builds logistic model without using intercept

Tags: python, data-science, logistic-regression, statsmodels

We have observed that stats model s logistic regression dosent shows where as scikit learn shows  intercept in model summary. if stats model dosent consider intercept  while model building. How it
builds model.

From my understanding while building logistic model algorithm learns beta values and intercept
and create equation

**Prediction =  logisticfunc(B0x0 + B1x1 + B2x2 +B3x3 + . . . + Bn xn + intercept)**

Comment: Statsmodels takes the design matrix as given by the user and does not add a constant. When formulas are used, then  a constant is added by default and any required transformations specified in the formula are performed. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723339/ols-of-statsmodels-does-not-work-with-inversely-proportional-data

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428825/different-coefficients-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels-logistic-regression for comparison statsmodels, sklearn for logit